I *think* my problem is Thunderbolt
I have a Dell XPS 13 9340, with latest bios 1.70, running fully patched Ubuntu 24.04 Desktop. Everything runs great...except my Anker 556 hub won't work. Mind you, the Anker 556 isn't Thunderbolt, its just a hub that can do USB4. But, I'm plugging it into a Thunderbolt4 port...
Based on kernel documentation, I've applied this udev rule:
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="thunderbolt", ATTRS{iommu_dma_protection}=="1", ATTR{authorized}=="0", ATTR{authorized}="1"

When I plug in the Anker 556 hub, I can see the system mount the Thunderbolt controller:
[    1.051480] kernel: ACPI: bus type thunderbolt registered
[    1.053748] kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.053756] kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.055227] kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: hcc params 0x20007fc1 hci version 0x120 quirks 0x0000000200009810
[    1.055558] kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.055561] kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    1.055564] kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Host supports USB 3.2 Enhanced SuperSpeed
[    1.055815] kernel: usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 6.08
[    1.055819] kernel: usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.055820] kernel: usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.055821] kernel: usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 6.8.0-1008-oem xhci-hcd
[    1.055822] kernel: usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0

It sees the Anker 556 just fine:
[    1.807165] kernel: usb 1-1.5: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    1.910660] kernel: usb 1-1.5: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[    1.917804] kernel: usb 1-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=291a, idProduct=83a8, bcdDevice=10.02
[    1.917809] kernel: usb 1-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    1.917811] kernel: usb 1-1.5: Product: USB2.0 Billboard N0
[    1.917812] kernel: usb 1-1.5: Manufacturer: Anker
[    1.917813] kernel: usb 1-1.5: SerialNumber: AHCZ340E20200065

However, according to journalctl -u bolt, I have issues:
Jul 22 13:44:26 netbook systemd[1]: Starting bolt.service - Thunderbolt system service...
Jul 22 13:44:26 netbook boltd[1846]: bolt 0.9.7 starting up.
Jul 22 13:44:26 netbook boltd[1846]: manager: initializing store
Jul 22 13:44:26 netbook boltd[1846]: store: located at: /var/lib/boltd
Jul 22 13:44:26 netbook boltd[1846]: config: loading user config
Jul 22 13:44:26 netbook boltd[1846]: config: user config loaded successfully
Jul 22 13:44:26 netbook boltd[1846]: config: auth mode set to 'enabled'
Jul 22 13:44:26 netbook boltd[1846]: bouncer: initializing polkit
Jul 22 13:44:26 netbook boltd[1846]: watchdog: enabled [pulse: 90s]
Jul 22 13:44:26 netbook boltd[1846]: udev: initializing udev
Jul 22 13:44:26 netbook boltd[1846]: store: loading domains
Jul 22 13:44:26 netbook boltd[1846]: store: loading devices
Jul 22 13:44:26 netbook boltd[1846]: power: state located at: /run/boltd/power
Jul 22 13:44:26 netbook boltd[1846]: power: force power support: no
Jul 22 13:44:26 netbook boltd[1846]: udev: enumerating devices
Jul 22 13:44:26 netbook boltd[1846]: [aa1b8780-f062-domain0                    ] newly connected [iommu+user] (/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.2/domain0/0-0)
Jul 22 13:44:26 netbook boltd[1846]: security level set to 'user'
Jul 22 13:44:26 netbook boltd[1846]: [aa1b8780-f062-domain0                    ] domain: registered (bootacl: 0/0)
Jul 22 13:44:26 netbook boltd[1846]: [aa1b8780-f062-domain0                    ] bootacl: bootacl not supported, no sync
Jul 22 13:44:26 netbook boltd[1846]: [aa1b8780-f062-domain0                    ] udev: failed to determine if uid is stable: unknown NHI PCI id '0x7ec2'
Jul 22 13:44:26 netbook boltd[1846]: [aa1b8780-f062-domain0                    ] udev: uuid is stable: no (for NHI: 0x7ec2)
Jul 22 13:44:26 netbook boltd[1846]: global 'generation' set to '4'
Jul 22 13:44:26 netbook boltd[1846]: [aa1b8780-f062-Gen14                      ] device added, status: authorized, at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.2/domain0/0-0
Jul 22 13:44:26 netbook boltd[1846]: [aa1b8780-f062-Gen14                      ] labeling device: Intel Gen14
Jul 22 13:44:26 netbook boltd[1846]: [8d1c8780-0170-domain1                    ] newly connected [iommu+user] (/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.3/domain1/1-0)
Jul 22 13:44:26 netbook boltd[1846]: [8d1c8780-0170-domain1                    ] domain: registered (bootacl: 0/0)
Jul 22 13:44:26 netbook boltd[1846]: [8d1c8780-0170-domain1                    ] bootacl: bootacl not supported, no sync
Jul 22 13:44:26 netbook boltd[1846]: [8d1c8780-0170-domain1                    ] udev: failed to determine if uid is stable: unknown NHI PCI id '0x7ec3'
Jul 22 13:44:26 netbook boltd[1846]: [8d1c8780-0170-domain1                    ] udev: uuid is stable: no (for NHI: 0x7ec3)
Jul 22 13:44:26 netbook boltd[1846]: [8d1c8780-0170-Gen14                      ] device added, status: authorized, at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.3/domain1/1-0
Jul 22 13:44:26 netbook boltd[1846]: [8d1c8780-0170-Gen14                      ] labeling device: Intel Gen14
Jul 22 13:44:26 netbook boltd[1846]: [aa1b8780-f062-domain0                    ] dbus: exported domain at /org/freedesktop/bolt/domains/aa1b8780_f062_2d03_ffff_ffffffffffff
Jul 22 13:44:26 netbook boltd[1846]: [8d1c8780-0170-domain1                    ] dbus: exported domain at /org/freedesktop/bolt/domains/8d1c8780_0170_8512_ffff_ffffffffffff
Jul 22 13:44:26 netbook boltd[1846]: [aa1b8780-f062-Gen14                      ] dbus: exported device at /org/freedesktop/bolt/devices/aa1b8780_f062...
Jul 22 13:44:26 netbook boltd[1846]: [8d1c8780-0170-Gen14 

boltctl seems fine:
root@netbook:~/.cargo/bin# boltctl list --all
Intel Gen14
   ├─ type:          host
   ├─ name:          Gen14
   ├─ vendor:        Intel
   ├─ uuid:          aa1b8780-f062-2d03-ffff-ffffffffffff
   ├─ generation:    USB4
   ├─ status:        authorized
   │  ├─ domain:     aa1b8780-f062-2d03-ffff-ffffffffffff
   │  └─ authflags:  none
   ├─ authorized:    Mon 22 Jul 2024 05:43:47 PM UTC
   ├─ connected:     Mon 22 Jul 2024 05:43:47 PM UTC
   └─ stored:        no
 Intel Gen14
   ├─ type:          host
   ├─ name:          Gen14
   ├─ vendor:        Intel
   ├─ uuid:          8d1c8780-0170-8512-ffff-ffffffffffff
   ├─ generation:    USB4
   ├─ status:        authorized
   │  ├─ domain:     8d1c8780-0170-8512-ffff-ffffffffffff
   │  └─ authflags:  none
   ├─ authorized:    Mon 22 Jul 2024 05:43:47 PM UTC
   ├─ connected:     Mon 22 Jul 2024 05:43:47 PM UTC
   └─ stored:        no

It will briefly do power delivery and the battery status shows as charging. But it quickly dies...
But, if I use Intel Thunderbolt tools, I get this:
root@netbook:~/.cargo/bin# ./tblist
Domain 0 Route 0: 8087:7eb2 Intel Gen14
Domain 1 Route 0: 8087:7eb2 Intel Gen14
root@netbook:~/.cargo/bin# ./tbadapters --route 0
 1: Lane 0                        CLd       
 2: Lane 1                        CLd       
 3: Lane 0                        CLd       
 4: Lane 1                        CLd       
 5: DisplayPort IN                Disabled  
 6: DisplayPort IN                Disabled  
 7: Host Interface (upstream)     Unknown   
 8: PCIe Down                     Disabled  
 9: PCIe Down                     Disabled  
10: Not implemented
11: Not implemented
12: USB 3 Down                    Disabled  
13: USB 3 Down                    Disabled  

udev logs show it getting added and removed, endlessly:

KERNEL[3191.118840] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.3/domain1/1-0/usb4_port3/1-0:3.1 (thunderbolt)
UDEV  [3191.119446] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.3/domain1/1-0/usb4_port3/1-0:3.1 (thunderbolt)
KERNEL[3191.130663] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.3/domain1/1-0/usb4_port3/1-0:3.1/nvm_active0 (nvmem)
KERNEL[3191.130674] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.3/domain1/1-0/usb4_port3/1-0:3.1/nvm_non_active0 (nvmem)
UDEV  [3191.131689] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.3/domain1/1-0/usb4_port3/1-0:3.1/nvm_active0 (nvmem)
UDEV  [3191.131866] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.3/domain1/1-0/usb4_port3/1-0:3.1/nvm_non_active0 (nvmem)
KERNEL[3191.188396] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card1/card1-eDP-1/intel_backlight (backlight)
UDEV  [3191.189204] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card1/card1-eDP-1/intel_backlight (backlight)
KERNEL[3192.590939] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card1/card1-eDP-1/intel_backlight (backlight)
UDEV  [3192.591966] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card1/card1-eDP-1/intel_backlight (backlight)
KERNEL[3192.769644] change   /devices/platform/ACPI0003:00/power_supply/AC (power_supply)
UDEV  [3192.770453] change   /devices/platform/ACPI0003:00/power_supply/AC (power_supply)
KERNEL[3192.776745] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0 (power_supply)
UDEV  [3192.777408] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0 (power_supply)
KERNEL[3193.292329] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card1/card1-eDP-1/intel_backlight (backlight)
UDEV  [3193.293421] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card1/card1-eDP-1/intel_backlight (backlight)
KERNEL[3193.993591] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card1/card1-eDP-1/intel_backlight (backlight)
UDEV  [3193.995311] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card1/card1-eDP-1/intel_backlight (backlight)
KERNEL[3195.610633] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.3/domain1/1-0/usb4_port3/1-0:3.1/nvm_non_active0 (nvmem)
KERNEL[3195.610664] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.3/domain1/1-0/usb4_port3/1-0:3.1/nvm_active0 (nvmem)
KERNEL[3195.610674] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.3/domain1/1-0/usb4_port3/1-0:3.1 (thunderbolt)
UDEV  [3195.611486] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.3/domain1/1-0/usb4_port3/1-0:3.1/nvm_non_active0 (nvmem)
UDEV  [3195.611496] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.3/domain1/1-0/usb4_port3/1-0:3.1/nvm_active0 (nvmem)
UDEV  [3195.611948] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.3/domain1/1-0/usb4_port3/1-0:3.1 (thunderbolt)
KERNEL[3196.265705] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0 (power_supply)
UDEV  [3196.266430] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0 (power_supply)
KERNEL[3197.090238] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.3/domain1/1-0/usb4_port3/1-0:3.1 (thunderbolt)
UDEV  [3197.092196] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.3/domain1/1-0/usb4_port3/1-0:3.1 (thunderbolt)
KERNEL[3197.102952] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.3/domain1/1-0/usb4_port3/1-0:3.1/nvm_active0 (nvmem)
KERNEL[3197.102962] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.3/domain1/1-0/usb4_port3/1-0:3.1/nvm_non_active0 (nvmem)
UDEV  [3197.103481] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.3/domain1/1-0/usb4_port3/1-0:3.1/nvm_non_active0 (nvmem)
UDEV  [3197.103591] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.3/domain1/1-0/usb4_port3/1-0:3.1/nvm_active0 (nvmem)
KERNEL[3198.414389] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1 (usb)
KERNEL[3198.415189] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1 (usb)
KERNEL[3198.415202] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[3198.417732] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[3198.417749] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1 (usb)
UDEV  [3198.421816] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1 (usb)
UDEV  [3198.422826] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1 (usb)
UDEV  [3198.423398] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [3198.424478] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [3198.425486] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1 (usb)
KERNEL[3198.813650] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5 (usb)
KERNEL[3198.823452] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:2.0 (usb)
KERNEL[3198.823469] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5 (usb)
KERNEL[3198.968676] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6 (usb)
KERNEL[3198.969059] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[3198.969074] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6 (usb)
UDEV  [3198.977144] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5 (usb)
UDEV  [3198.977462] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6 (usb)
UDEV  [3198.978175] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:2.0 (usb)
UDEV  [3198.978200] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [3198.978737] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5 (usb)
UDEV  [3198.979066] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6 (usb)
KERNEL[3201.581418] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.3/domain1/1-0/usb4_port3/1-0:3.1/nvm_non_active0 (nvmem)
KERNEL[3201.581444] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.3/domain1/1-0/usb4_port3/1-0:3.1/nvm_active0 (nvmem)
KERNEL[3201.581450] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.3/domain1/1-0/usb4_port3/1-0:3.1 (thunderbolt)
UDEV  [3201.583020] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.3/domain1/1-0/usb4_port3/1-0:3.1/nvm_non_active0 (nvmem)
UDEV  [3201.583031] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.3/domain1/1-0/usb4_port3/1-0:3.1/nvm_active0 (nvmem)
UDEV  [3201.583538] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.3/domain1/1-0/usb4_port3/1-0:3.1 (thunderbolt)
KERNEL[3202.554075] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:2.0 (usb)
KERNEL[3202.555293] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5 (usb)
KERNEL[3202.555592] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5 (usb)
KERNEL[3202.555753] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[3202.556076] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6 (usb)
KERNEL[3202.556232] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6 (usb)
KERNEL[3202.558365] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[3202.558584] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[3202.559880] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1 (usb)
KERNEL[3202.560238] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1 (usb)
UDEV  [3202.563141] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:2.0 (usb)
UDEV  [3202.563416] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [3202.569188] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0 (usb)

I've looked all over the bios, and enabled everything Thunderbolt related. However, this bios DOES NOT have Security Levels for Thunderbolt. I'm not sure why.
I have an XPS 13 9370 from 2019, and as soon as I move the USB4 cable to it, it registers everything just fine.
How can I troubleshoot this?
Edit 1: Adding some info...
I can't seem to find Thunderbolt Security controls in the Bios.
I also updated the bios to v1.8.0 and still have the same issue. However, I've been messing around with Dell Command, and it seems that I'm totally missing Thunderbolt security controls...
$ sudo /opt/dell/dcc/cctk --ThunderboltSecLvl

The option 'ThunderboltSecLvl' is not available or cannot be configured
through this tool.

Edit 2:
Based on some additional testing, it seems like everything works when I boot into the OS while the Anker hub is plugged in. When I unplug and put back in, I run into the issue.
Edit 3:
I just installed Windows 11 to test, and it works perfectly fine...
Edit 4:
Okay, more info... Things stopped working since my Edit 2.
I had to downgrad my kernel to linux-image-6.5.0-1020-oem
Then I made sure that I used boltctl to enroll and authorize the Thunderbolt domains again.
Then I shutdown, and booted while the Anker hub was plugged in.
Now, the Anker hub is recognized as a Thunderbolt 4 hub, and authorized. You can confirm this in Settings, or by:
# boltctl list
 ● Anker USB4 Device
   ├─ type:          peripheral
   ├─ name:          USB4 Device
   ├─ vendor:        Anker
   ├─ uuid:          3aa70921-50f3-b0aa-ffff-ffffffffffff
   ├─ generation:    USB4
   ├─ status:        authorized
   │  ├─ domain:     2e688780-3101-be55-ffff-ffffffffffff
   │  ├─ rx speed:   20 Gb/s = 2 lanes * 10 Gb/s
   │  ├─ tx speed:   20 Gb/s = 2 lanes * 10 Gb/s
   │  └─ authflags:  none
   ├─ authorized:    Fri 04 Oct 2024 05:18:05 PM UTC
   ├─ connected:     Fri 04 Oct 2024 05:18:05 PM UTC
   └─ stored:        no

HOWEVER! I still cannot hotplug the Anker hub. If I pull the USB-C and replug it, I am back to square one of it not working at all.

Well, after multiple months of battling this issue, I think it is finally fixed.
I patched my bios to v1.12.0 AND manually installed kernel 6.12.3.
Now, hotplugging the Anker finally works.

Some newer Dell models may hide certain settings by default. Perform a BIOS reset to factory defaults, then re-check for Thunderbolt security options under Security or System Configuration.
Now check for the Thunderbolt security options. If it still isn't visible, perform a CMOS reset. That can resolve issues where BIOS settings are not displaying properly.
In BIOS, set Thunderbolt security to "No Security", and make sure Thunderbolt Pre-boot Support is enabled.
Disable any specific Thunderbolt-related settings and let the USB4 hub operate in pure USB mode.
Disable IOMMU: Add intel_iommu=off to your GRUB configuration.
Re-detection in Linux:

Run: sudo modprobe -r thunderbolt && sudo modprobe thunderbolt
Check boltctl to confirm whether the device is re-detected and correctly authorized.

I have a slightly older Dell model, I went through something similar.
Let me know if the issue is not resolved, that rabbit hole ain't that deep.
Good luck!

According to the specs, this should work fine without issues, by reading what Dell says, it should work and I would also have bought the laptop, it looks nice!

iommu=pt did not help :(
There is NO place in the bios for me to set the Thunderbolt security. Very odd.
I have an XPS 13 9370 from 2019, and it works just fine.

I have edited my answer. Thunderbolt security options is there (hidden or very hard to find), Microsoft forces the manufacturers to include it for their "secure systems", finding that is imperative to get this right.

Okay, [without performing your recommendations] I've found that everything works when I boot the system with the Anker hub plugged in. I wasn't doing this before. However, if I unplug and plug back in, I get the results that I've described in my original post. So, it seems to be a hotplug issue. I've tried fresh Ubuntu install from 22.04 and 24.04, and even Dell's Recovery Ubuntu image.

FYI - I just installed Windows 11 to test, and it works perfectly fine with no additional configuration...
